# How to exclude lowercase string in replace RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

i have code like this, and i want to exclude lowercase word from RegEx replace?

```js
let str = "a A am Am a# A# a#d A#d";
 let obj = {
     'A': 'a-uppercase',
     'Am': 'a-minor',
     'A#': 'a-hasgtag',
     'A#d': 'a-minor-d',
 };
 
 function allReplace(par_one, par_two) {
            for (const x in obj) {
                let rx = new RegExp(
                    "(^|\\s)" + x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&") + "(?!\\S)",
                    "gi"
                );
                console.log(obj[x]);
                str = str.replace(rx, "$1" + obj[x]);
            }
            return str;
        }

console.log(allReplace(str, obj));
```

when i console log:

```
a-uppercase a-uppercase a-minor a-minor a-hasgtag a-hasgtag a-minor-d a-minor-d
```

my expectation console log is:

```
a a-uppercase am a-minor a# a-hasgtag a#d a-hasgtag-d
```

how can i do from this?

Comment: `"gi"` - the `i` flag will perform a case-insensitive search. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags

Comment: The "gi" flag ensures that the replacement is done globally and in a case-insensitive manner. If you want to exclude lowercase words from replacement, you might want to modify your regular expression to explicitly check for uppercase versions of the words. For example, you can replace the "gi" flag with just "g" and handle the case sensitivity separately.

Comment: Are you sure the output should be `a a-uppercase am a-minor a# a-hasgtag a#d a-hasgtag-d` and not `a a-uppercase am a-minor a# a-hasgtag a#d a-minor-d`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

remove the "i" flag from the RegExp, make the matches case-sensitive

```js
let str = "a A am Am a# A# a#d A#d";

let obj = {
    'A': 'a-uppercase',
    'Am': 'a-minor',
    'A#': 'a-hasgtag',
    'A#d': 'a-minor-d',
};

function allReplace(par_one, par_two) {
    for (const x in obj) {
        let rx = new RegExp(
            "(^|\\s)" + x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&") + "(?=\\s|$)",
            "g"
        );
        str = str.replace(rx, (match, p1) => {
            return match.charAt(0) === match.charAt(0).toUpperCase() ? p1 + obj[x] : match;
        });
    }
    return str;
}

console.log(allReplace(str, obj));
```

Comment: With this, the word at the end becomes `a-minor-d`, but OP needs it to be `a-hasgtag-d`